# Solving functional equation involving infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

I am trying to solve for a continuous function $h(z)$ given the following equation:
$$h(z)=\left\{\begin{array}
 &g(z)\text{ when z is non-integer}\\
 g_i(z)\text{ when z is integer}\\
 \end{array}\right.$$$$g(z)=e^{z}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2k}g_i(2k)}{z-2k}$$
$g_i(n)$ is a zero terminating recursive function defined for integer values by:

$$g{_i}(n)=\left\{\begin{array}
 &0\text{ when $n=0$} \\ 
 0\text{ when n is odd}\\
 g_i(\frac{n}{2})+1\text{ when $n$ non-zero and even}\\
 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I get $g(1)=0$ as you say, but then I get $g(2) = \frac{\pi}{2}g(2)$, which does not agree with what you said.

Comment: I think that the integer $g(n)$ taken on its own is meant to count the number of factors of 2 in $n$. However I have no idea how the integer version of $g$ relates to the other version. The sum $g(z)$ seems to blow up when even $z$ is equal to $2k$; only saved by the fact that $\sin(\pi z)=0$ for even and as well as odd integer $n$. In this respect at least $g(z)$ has a different behaviour $g(n)$: why have they been given the same function name?

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the question please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: The definition of $g_i(n)$ doesn't make sense for $n=0$. It gives $g_i(0)=g_i(0)+1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: attempted the fix for the mistake at $n=0$

Comment: What's to solve? There is no equation. I see a definition of a function $h(z)$. Admittedly, it is somewhat complicated, but still pretty manageable.